# Retaining metadata when subsetting in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with `data.table` in R that contain metadata (stored in the "comment" attribute) that provides a time stamp of the data.  When subsetting the data.table, the metadata gets dropped.  For example,

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = c(1:5), y = c(6:10))
setattr(dt, 'comment', 'december 10, 2015')
comment(dt)                  # The metadata is present here...
# [1] "december 10, 2015"
comment(dt[x < 3])           # ...but not retained here
# NULL
```

`data.frame`, on the other hand, does not exhibit the same behavior.  For example,

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(6:10))
comment(df) <- "december 2015"
comment(df)              # Metadata again is present
# [1] "december 2015"
comment(df[df$x < 3, ])  # Metadata is retained
# [1] "december 2015"
```

Does anyone know if there a way to have `data.table` retain the metadata in these subsets?

Comment: OP, submit an issue to github

Comment: there is mine issue about that somewhere there :)

Comment: This works now : https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/995

Answer (score 1):

This works since [1.12.0](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3250), see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/995

```
comment(dt[x < 3])   
[1] "december 10, 2015"
```